# Scraping an html table, how to have the info in a similar structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a html table that looks like this:

```
Recent ratings:
thew              26-6-2014 11:02     Karma   +4      lucky you
user34            26-6-2014 10:34     Karma   +3      great!
godspeed          26-6-2014 06:50     Karma   +5      thanks!
                                                                [Report to Mod.]
```

I use Beautiful Soup, and my code includes this:

```
five = soup.findAll("fieldset")

for html in five:
            text5 = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("   ", "")
            karmas.append(text5.split("Recent Ratings")[1].split("[Report to Mod.]")[0].strip())
```

The result, in a csv file, is one column that looks like this:

```
thew
ￂﾠￂﾠ26-6-2014 11:02ￂﾠￂﾠKarmaￂﾠￂﾠ+4
ￂﾠￂﾠlucky you
user34
ￂﾠￂﾠ26-6-2014 10:34ￂﾠￂﾠKarmaￂﾠￂﾠ+3
ￂﾠￂﾠgreat!
godspeed
ￂﾠￂﾠ26-6-2014 06:50ￂﾠￂﾠKarmaￂﾠￂﾠ+5
ￂﾠￂﾠthanks!
```

How can I separate the information in a structure that is similar to the table?

I tried adding .replace("\n", ""), and the result is all the info in one line:

```
thewￂﾠￂﾠ26-6-2014 11:02ￂﾠￂﾠKarmaￂﾠￂﾠ+4ￂﾠￂﾠlucky youuser34ￂﾠￂﾠ26-6-2014 10:34ￂﾠￂﾠKarmaￂﾠￂﾠ+3ￂﾠￂﾠgreat!godspeedￂﾠￂﾠ26-6-2014 06:50ￂﾠￂﾠKarmaￂﾠￂﾠ+5ￂﾠￂﾠthanks!
```

Here's what I get when I print 'five'.

```
[<fieldset><legend><a href="misc.php?action=viewratings&amp;tid=50510&amp;pid=502926" title="View Rating Log">Recent Ratings</a></legend><br/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=21445" target="_blank">thew</a></td>
<td>  26-6-2014 11:02</td><td>  Karma</td><td>  <b>+4</b></td>
<td>  lucky you</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=43867" target="_blank">user34</a></td>
<td>  26-6-2014 10:34</td><td>  Karma</td><td>  <b>+3</b></td>
<td>  great!</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=68709" target="_blank">godspeed</a></td>
<td>  26-6-2014 06:50</td><td>  Karma</td><td>  <b>+5</b></td>
<td>  thanks!</td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>]
```

The answer below works when I print the output, but not when I write it to a csv. An excerpt from my code:

```
five = soup.findAll("fieldset")

karmas = []

for i in five:
    for j in  i.findAll('td'):
        somevar = j.text
        print somevar           
        karmas.append(somevar.strip())

        csvfile = open('test.csv', 'ab')    
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        for karma in zip(karmas):
                writer.writerow([karma])

        csvfile.close()

#output print somevar

thew
  26-6-2014 11:02
  Karma
  +4
  lucky you
user34
  26-6-2014 10:34
  Karma
  +3
  great!
godspeed
  26-6-2014 06:50
  Karma
  +5
  thanks!

# output in csv

thew
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you can give the output of `five` here .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just added what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `soup.findAll("fieldset")` use `soup.findAll("tr")` inside the fieldset

```
html=''' <fieldset><legend><a href="misc.php?action=viewratings&amp;tid=50510&amp;pid=502926" title="View Rating Log">Recent Ratings</a></legend><br/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=21445" target="_blank">thew</a></td>
<td>  26-6-2014 11:02</td><td>  Karma</td><td>  <b>+4</b></td>
<td>  lucky you</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=43867" target="_blank">user34</a></td>
<td>  26-6-2014 10:34</td><td>  Karma</td><td>  <b>+3</b></td>
<td>  great!</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=68709" target="_blank">godspeed</a></td>
<td>  26-6-2014 06:50</td><td>  Karma</td><td>  <b>+5</b></td>
<td>  thanks!</td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset> '''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
five = soup.findAll("tr")
for i in five:
    with open('some.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow([j.text for j in  i.findAll('td')])

#output

thew   26-6-2014 11:02   Karma  +4   lucky you
user34   26-6-2014 10:34   Karma  +3   great!
godspeed   26-6-2014 06:50   Karma  +5   thanks!
```

Comment: It looks like this will work, but only in this particular example with these three users? I need to do this for thousands of html files in which the feedback will be different, from different users.

Comment: The code is totally independent of data. Provided that the html files have the same structure, this should scrap comment for any number of users on any file.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! It definitely works when printed, as above. However, when I try to write this to my csv the output is only 'thew', i.e. the name of the first user -- everything is left out. I've updated my question above to explain!

Comment: Sundar, any thoughts on how I can get the text to a csv? Please see the updated question. I hope you can help!